# Rails 3.1 Remote Button Unobtrusive Javascript event not caught (JQuery)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to start using the Ajax events ajax:success, ajax:failure, ajax:complete and ajax:beforeSend as recommended for unobtrusive Javascript in posts like:

- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/
- http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/

But for some reason it's not working for me. I am missing something (something small) as I cannot get the events to trigger my Javascript. I am hoping someone could spot the "obvious" mistake/omission in my code.

Some details on my environment:

- Rails 3.1
- jQuery (jquery-rails gem)
- therubyracer for server side js processing (not that it should matter for my example)

To try and work out what I am missing I have created a simple test application which has a single remote button to. When the button is clicked, I want alert boxes to fire. The code of this app can be seen on github here:

http://github.com/jpmcgrath/rbtest

I have deployed the application to heroku here:

http://rbtest.heroku.com/projects/

If you look at the app, you can click the button and the button successfully creates a new project (to see it manually refresh), but ajax:success event doesn't seem to happen?

The guts of the code is as follows:

In projects_controller.rb

```
def remote_test
  @project = Project.new(:name => "remote test")

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      puts "project saved!\n\n\n"
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

In application.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".remote_button").click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  })
  .bind("ajax:complete", function() {
    alert('complete!');
  })
  .bind("ajax:beforeSend", function () {
    alert('loading!');
  })
  .bind("ajax:error", function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert('failure!');
  })
  .bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert('success!');
  });
});
```

In the view projects/index.html.erb

```
<%= button_to "remote test", remote_test_path, :remote => true, :class => 'remote_button'  %>
```

If anyone could point out what I am missing (I suspect it has something to do with response type) it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason your event handler is not firing is because your selector is on the wrong element. button_to creates a form with a single input tag, and it's that input tag that has the class your selecting on, but the ajax events are triggered on the form, not the input tag.

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".remote_button").click(function() {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
  });

  jQuery("form.button_to").bind("ajax:complete", function() {
    alert('complete!');
  })
  .bind("ajax:beforeSend", function () {
    alert('loading!');
  })
  .bind("ajax:error", function (xhr, status, error) {
    alert('failure!');
  })
  .bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
    alert('success!');
  });
});
```

I did the equivalent in my firebug console and it fired the ajax:success handler when the callback was on the form.

To change the class on the form use the :form_class option to change it from button_to to something else

```
<%= button_to "remote test", remote_test_path, :remote => true, :class => 'remote_button', :form_class => 'remote_button_form' %>
```

Then add your ajax callbacks using

```
jQuery(".remote_button_form").bind ...
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it! Also, you have a typo in your suggested code. ".remove_button_form" should be ".remote_button_form". Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Rails has changed how javascript files are handled.

Railscasts has a few examples.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

http://railscasts.com/episodes/267-coffeescript-basics?autoplay=true

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am aware of these changes, but I don't think this is the cause of my problem. For my example app I have avoided using coffeescript because I wanted to simplify. The js I have used seems to be working as when the button is clicked an js alert is shown saying 'Handler for .click() called.'